# how to call NSE api for historical data free

Tags: node.js

I am build some sort of finance report and want to fetch data from NSE. for that I am using following api.
Please replace test placeholder with any valid symbol. now when I hit url from browser it works fine and return simple Json.

[https://www.nseindia.com/api/quote-equity?symbol={test}](https://www.nseindia.com/api/quote-equity?symbol=%7Btest%7D)

but when I am trying to call it from code then it did not return anything and hanged for forever.
If calling it from postman then it return 401.  now the strange thing is

```
function nse(url){    
    let oReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
    oReq.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (oReq.readyState === 4) {
            console.log(oReq.status);
            console.log(oReq.responseText);
        }
    }

    oReq.open("GET", url);
    oReq.send();
}

nse("https://www.nseindia.com");
```

I tried calling the base url of nse site as well and still issue is same. as per my understanding its public site and it should provide data for use.

can someone help me on this?

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a Http Header with a User-Agent impersonate a browser like Firefox or Chrome, then make sure to create a session and call the api. This method works as I have tried it in one of my projects.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Check on bellows git repo, it implement on NSE India web api
[jugaad-data](https://github.com/jugaad-py/jugaad-data)